# Air for android application runs slow after a while, what to do?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm making an app in flash Professional. It's basically an advanced avoider game, with some objects being spawned and shooting after the character and so on. When i open the app on my mobile, it runs smoothly as it's supposed to, but after a while, it runs noticeably slower, not much, but enough to be annoying, and ruin the experience a little.
I've been careful with using removeChild, so that every object is deleted when you clear a level and such.

Can I expect there to be a memory leak, since there is no lag in the beginning?
And what would be a good idea to do or look up? 
Should I use garbage collection, and is it possible to analyse the app with scout or flash builder? any good tutorials??
Thanks in advance

//_______________________Differnet event listeners ______________________

```
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveWorld)

        mainMenu.PlayButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWorldMap)
        mainMenu.closebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeAppdown)
        gamePanel.jetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, jetPackUp)
        gamePanel.jetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, jetPackStop)
        gamePanel.jumpButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startJumping)
        gamePanel.jumpButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopSwimming)

        gameOverScreen.RestartButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, restartLevel)
        gameOverScreen.backtoMenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backtoWorldMap)

        nextLevel.nextLevelButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoNextLevel)
        nextLevel.backtoWorldMap.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backworldMap)

        pauseScreen.continueButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, continueGame)

        wannaLeave.YesEndGame.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, endingGame)
        wannaLeave.backToMain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goingMain)
```

//__________________________ Eventlisteners for different buttons, that send to each its level _____________

```
        worldMap.buttonWorld1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWorld1)
        ...etc...
        worldMap.buttonWorld27.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWorld27)

        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,checkKeypress);
```

//_________________________For loops for things that are in arrays _________________________

```
        for (var l:int = 0; l<14; l++)
        {
            var lavaThing:LavaThing = new LavaThing;
            lavas.push(lavaThing);
        }
        for (var v:int = 0; v<14; v++)
        {
            var upsideVolcano:UpsideVolcano = new UpsideVolcano;
            volcanos.push(upsideVolcano);
        }
        for (var j:int = 0; j<7; j++)
        {
            var jetFuel:JetFuel = new JetFuel;
            fuels.push(jetFuel);
        }
        for (var m:int = 0; m<3; m++)
        {
            var monster:Monster = new Monster;
            monsterArmy.push(monster);
        }
    }
```

//_________________ Make world go to the right frame, along with dangers etc... _______

```
    public function gotoWorld()
    {
        isonWorldMap = false;
        isinGame = true;

        addChild(backGround);
        backGround.x = 0;
        backGround.y = 0;

        addChild(backGroundPlanet);
        backGroundPlanet.x = 0;
        backGroundPlanet.y = 0;

        addChild(world);
        world.x = 0;
        world.y = 0;
        isinWorld = true

        addChild(character);
        character.x = 100;
        character.y = 350;
        character.gotoAndStop(3);
        addChild(gamePanel);

        addChild(fuelBar);
        fuelBar.x = 521.85;
        fuelBar.y = 492.6;

        if (currentLevel<12)
        {
            Different movespeed
        }else if (currentLevel>11)
        {
            Different Movespeed
        }
        if (currentLevel == 1)
        {
        world.worldDangers.gotoAndStop(1);
        world.SafeGround.gotoAndStop(1);
        world.GroundViz.gotoAndStop(1);
        world.PortaltoNew.gotoAndStop(1);
        world.Water.gotoAndStop(1);

        character.scaleY = 1;
        character.scaleX = 1;


        world.GroundViz.addChild(fuels[0])
        fuels[0].x = 307.15;
        fuels[0].y = -1855.75;

        maxStamina = 500;
        stamina = 0;
        }
        ...etc...
        }else if (currentLevel == 12)
        {
        world.worldDangers.gotoAndStop(12);
        world.SafeGround.gotoAndStop(12);
        world.GroundViz.gotoAndStop(12);
        world.PortaltoNew.gotoAndStop(12);
        world.Water.gotoAndStop(12);
        character.scaleY = 0.7;
        character.scaleX = 0.7;
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[0])
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[1])
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[2])
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[3])
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[4])
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[5])

        lavas[0].x = 83.3;
        lavas[0].y = -356.8;
        lavas[0].rotation = -10

        lavas[1].x = 118;
        lavas[1].y = -130.95;

        lavas[2].x = -3373;
        lavas[2].y = -4433;

        lavas[3].x = -3373;
        lavas[3].y = -4773;

        lavas[4].x = -3373;
        lavas[4].y = -5068;

        lavas[5].x = -3373;
        lavas[5].y = -5408;

        world.GroundViz.addChild(fuels[0])
        world.GroundViz.addChild(fuels[1])
        world.GroundViz.addChild(fuels[2])
        world.GroundViz.addChild(fuels[3])
        world.GroundViz.addChild(fuels[4])

        fuels[0].x = 335.65;
        fuels[0].y = 163.55;
        fuels[1].x = -77.65;
        fuels[1].y = -976.45;
        fuels[2].x = -1292.1;
        fuels[2].y = -1686.9;
        fuels[3].x = -2343.05;
        fuels[3].y = -2696.05;
        fuels[4].x = -3034.2;
        fuels[4].y = -3861.75;


        maxStamina = 500;
        stamina = 0;¨
        ...etc...
        }else if (currentLevel == 13)
        {
        world.worldDangers.gotoAndStop(13);
        world.SafeGround.gotoAndStop(13);
        world.GroundViz.gotoAndStop(13);
        world.PortaltoNew.gotoAndStop(13);
        world.Water.gotoAndStop(13);

        character.scaleY = 0.7;
        character.scaleX = 0.7;



        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[0])
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[1])
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[2])
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[3])
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[4])
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[5])
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[6])
        world.worldDangers.addChild(lavas[7])


        lavas[0].x = -2535.75;
        lavas[0].y = -2614.5;

        lavas[1].x = -2535.75;
        lavas[1].y = -2809.6;

        lavas[2].x = -2535.75;
        lavas[2].y = -3019.7;

        lavas[3].x = -2535.75;
        lavas[3].y = -3219.8;

        lavas[4].x = -2790.9;
        lavas[4].y = -4770.65;

        lavas[5].x = -2790.9;
        lavas[5].y = -4985;

        lavas[6].x = -2790.9;
        lavas[6].y = -5195.85;

        lavas[7].x = -2790.9;
        lavas[7].y = -5421;

        world.GroundViz.addChild(fuels[0])
        world.GroundViz.addChild(fuels[1])
        world.GroundViz.addChild(fuels[2])
        world.GroundViz.addChild(fuels[3])
        world.GroundViz.addChild(fuels[4])

        fuels[0].x = 335.6;
        fuels[0].y = 66;
        fuels[1].x = -652.2;
        fuels[1].y = -1031.3;
        fuels[2].x = -2051.15;
        fuels[2].y = -2022.45;
        fuels[3].x = -2165.8;
        fuels[3].y = -3174;
        fuels[4].x = -1547.05;
        fuels[4].y = -4138.65;

        maxStamina = 500;
        stamina = 0;
        }
        ...etc...
        else if (currentLevel == 27)
        {
        world.worldDangers.gotoAndStop(27);
        world.SafeGround.gotoAndStop(27);
        world.GroundViz.gotoAndStop(27);
        world.PortaltoNew.gotoAndStop(27);
        world.Water.gotoAndStop(27);

        character.scaleY = 0.7;
        character.scaleX = 0.7;

        world.GroundViz.addChild(monsterArmy[0])
        monsterArmy[0].x = 1029.75;
        monsterArmy[0].y = -7823.5;

        maxStamina = 2500;
        stamina = 2500;
        }
    }
```

//___________________ Function called when character hits danger ______________

```
    public function charDies()
    {
        addChild(gameOverScreen);
        world.parent.removeChild(world);
        backGround.parent.removeChild(backGround);
        backGroundPlanet.parent.removeChild(backGroundPlanet);
        character.parent.removeChild(character);
        gamePanel.parent.removeChild(gamePanel);

        isinWorld = false;
        isinWater = false;
        jetIsBeingPressed = false;
        isinGame = false;
        jumping = false;

//____________________ Removes all the monsters, and volcano obstacles etc....

        for (var h = 0; h < lavas.length; h++) {
        if (lavas[h].parent) { //check to see if this item has a parent
        lavas[h].parent.removeChild(lavas[h]); //tell the parent to remove this child
            }
        }

        for (var v = 0; v < volcanos.length; v++) {
        if (volcanos[v].parent) { //check to see if this item has a parent
        volcanos[v].parent.removeChild(volcanos[v]); //tell the parent to remove this child
            }
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < fuels.length; j++) {
        if (fuels[j].parent) { //check to see if this item has a parent
        fuels[j].parent.removeChild(fuels[j]); //tell the parent to remove this child
            }
        }

        for (var m = 0; m < monsterArmy.length; m++) {
        if (monsterArmy[m].parent) { //check to see if this item has a parent
        monsterArmy[m].parent.removeChild(monsterArmy[m]); //tell the parent to remove this child

        System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent()
            }
        }

    }
```

//________________ Makes player able to try level again_____________________

```
    function restartLevel (m:MouseEvent):void 
    {           
        gameOverScreen.parent.removeChild(gameOverScreen);
        gotoWorld()
    }
```

//_________________ Level buttons ______________________

```
    function gotoWorld1 (m:MouseEvent):void
    {
        currentLevel = 1;
        worldMap.parent.removeChild(worldMap);
        gotoWorld();
    }
    ...etc...
    function gotoWorld27 (m:MouseEvent):void
    {
        currentLevel = 27;
        worldMap.parent.removeChild(worldMap);
        gotoWorld();
    }
```

//___________________________ MOVE WORLD _____________________________

```
    function moveWorld (e:Event)
    {
        trace(System.totalMemory);

        if (isinWorld)
        {
            world.x -= worldMoveSpeed;

            backGroundPlanet.x -= 0.3;

            if (backGroundPlanet.x < -300)
            {
                backGroundPlanet.x = -300;
            }
```

Comment: What to look for: too many object creations, not reusing resources, GC cycle pilling up, listeners not removed, too many enterframe used, too many timers, etc ...

Comment: This is too broad for StackOverflow.  Try and narrow it down and show the code you think is the culprit.     Make sure to remove event listeners (or make them weak references), that and not removing children is the most common cause of memory leaks.  Grant Skinner has a great article about garbage collection.  http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html

Comment: @moot I can't seem to turn on the advanced telemetry option in flash professional air for android, which is required i scout. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @LDMS Thanks for the articles. I've added quite a bit of code, since there is a lot of code in my game, but I've tried to reduce it as much as possible.When you play the game, and you've died some times, and won some times it starts to get slow, so I've added the code in which the level gets loaded, and the character dies.

Comment: It should be in the publish settings.  You have to use Scout.  It will show you instantly what percentage of cpu is being used by what code or process.

Comment: @moot So I found a video on how to enable advanced metrics on youtube, when I click publish settings, and click advanced, there isn't the same option as in the video.. I did notice that in the video it said air for iOS 3.6, and mine says 3.2... Isn't mine updated or something??

Comment: Yeah, update your Air SDK and keep it updated - it's what updates.  Current version is 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't get Adobe scout to work no matter what I did. But I did solve the problem.
For whom it might help:
I added 'trace(System.totalMemory);' in the document class' inside an ENTER_FRAME function, which made me able to see how much memory my app was using. In the beginning the amount was rising constantly. 
I moved all the eventlisteners from the main class, into whatever class was the best fit.
For Example I moved 'gamePanel.jetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, jetPackUp)' into the gamePanel class.
To reference the main class from inside the gamePanel class, i used the code: 'MovieClip(parent).someFunction()'
Now I allmost have a stabile app that doesn't keep using memory.
I just have to figure out what to do with my for loops, which causes memory leaks, when I have to add more instances of the same object.. But I think 'object pooling' will solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly use Scout to see how your memory is being used.

Here's a great memory tracking class that you can use to check that your instances are being released from memory when they should be.

http://divillysausages.com/blog/tracking_memory_leaks_in_as3

Comment: Thanks! I just can't enable advanced telematry in flash sc6 air for android, even when i change it to the latest air sdk.. the option just isn't there under publish settings, and under swf advanced. Is there another way?

Comment: You can publish the app from the command line and set the attributes manually.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c-24dc70c812b9cbf7285-8000.html